# Where to get Security Vulnerability Information?

Tags: security

Where can I get email or rss notifications (push), of currently new discovered security vulnerabilities in any kind of software.

Ideally the service should be free and it shoul allow me to subscribe to specific topics ideally in a tree-like structure like:
web-applications => blogs/cms => wordpress => wordpress plugins => plugin foobar

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! Might I also recommend [security.se], a site for Information Security folk. This question, unfortunately, is a bad fit for our format and will be off-ropic for any StackExchange site.

Comment: Thanks very much Scott! Didnt know the site you linked. Maybe someone can move my question over there (at least at stackoverflow moving is somehow possible)?

Answer (score 1):

The lists over at [seclists.org](http://seclists.org/) all have RSS feeds and are free to use. Both the `Bugtraq` and `Full Disclosure` lists are pretty high-volume and hold the latest information about discovered vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The two biggest lists that I know of are:

The DHS at NIST has the National Vulnerability Database "[feeds](http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm)" and an [email](http://nvd.nist.gov/home.cfm?emaillist) list.  I do not know what level of detail are in the emails but the feeds have everything.

Mitre Org has a Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures List(CVE) with updates by [email](http://cve.mitre.org/news/newsletter.html).